# Problem installing openni kinect in ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm having problems installing the openni kinect driver for ROS fuerte, when I type this:

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-openni-kinect

It gives me the following message:

"Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
ros-fuerte-openni-kinect : Depende: ros-fuerte-openni-camera (= 1.8.6-s1363175083~precise) pero no va a instalarse
Depende: ros-fuerte-openni-launch (= 1.8.3-s1363200146~precise) pero no va a instalarse
Depende: ros-fuerte-openni-tracker (= 0.1.3-s1363160164~precise) pero no va a instalarse
Depende: libopenni-dev pero no va a instalarse
Depende: libopenni-nite-dev pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos. "

Well, it is in spanish, but basically it is saying that this application depends on that programs but they are not going to be installed because "you have broken packages". What is wrong? I have installed the Full ROS Fuerte package with its repositories, coculd it be a problem with the repositories? may I need another repositories in order to install Openni kinect libraries? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60814/problem-installing-openni-kinect-in-ros-fuerte-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [dalogi84](https://answers.ros.org/users/4691/dalogi84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-06-05**:
similar error: Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-fuerte-openni-launch i386 1.8.3-s1367637426~precise  404  Not Found

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-06-05**:
I managed to install openni_camera but no success for openni_launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you may install the dependencies by hand, i.e sudo apt-get install ...
if you then encountered another dependencies problem, do that again. by tracing down the dependencies which are missing, you may finally resolve the problem. at least i solve such problems in this way. hope it will help

---

Originally posted by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) with karma: 155 on 2013-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0